# why not differenciate?

Tags: etymology

From *difference* (noun) and *different* (adj), the verb *differentiate* is derived.

However, why the verb form is not *differenciate*? Is it because it happened to be derived from the adj, not the noun? Or there're some other reason?

Comment: https://www.etymonline.com/word/differentiate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In one word? Latin. In two more? French mathematics.

*Differentiate* (orig. 1814) was first a mathematical term for finding the differential or derivative of something. It comes directly from *differentiat-*, the past participial stem of the verb *differentiare* (to distinguish). The Oxford English Dictionary entry ("[differentiate, v.](https://www.oed.com/view/Entry/52467)") discusses both the Latin root as well as the parallel French mathematical term *[différentier](https://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais-anglais/diff%C3%A9rentier/25334)* (first used in 1754 for mathematics according to the OED). So the French and Latin spellings greatly encourage the [t] spelling.

The word could have gone a different way. French has a more general word, *[différencier](https://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais-anglais/diff%C3%A9rencier/25320)*. If Laplace and other French mathematicians had kept the spelling *différencier* for mathematics as well as other meanings, then maybe John Toplis would have translated Laplace with the word *differenciating* in 1814 instead of *differentiating*:

> By *differentiating* [Fr. en *différentiant*] this last function, we shall have a differential equation. (Toplis's translation of Laplace, *A Treatise Upon Analytical Mechanics*, 1814, ii. 68)

So English mathematics received the [t] spelling, and once *differentiate* generalized beyond mathematics, the word kept the [t].